# 301 redirect URLs that are also being rewritten

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, slim

I am building a site using Slim, which suggests the following `.htaccess` code for creating pretty URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This means that a URL like `http://example.com/account/login` will **alias** for `http://example.com/index.php/account/login`, which is then processed by my front controller.  So far so good.

However, if someone explicitly navigates to

`http://example.com/index.php/account/login`,

I would like it to first **redirect** to:

`http://example.com/account/login`,

and **then** alias for

`http://example.com/index.php/account/login`.

That way, the user will see `http://example.com/account/login` in their navigation bar.

How can I handle both of these rules simultaneously in `.htaccess`, and most importantly, without hardcoding the host and domain (`http://example.com`) in `.htaccess`?

This should also work in a subdirectory, for example:

`http://example.com/site1/index.php/account/login` ->
`http://example.com/site1/account/login`

With the `.htaccess` file located in the `site1` directory relative to document root, and without having to explicitly put `site1` in the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new redirect rule before this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:BASE}$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, I saw your answer in another question but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  If I have `^` at the beginning of the `RewriteRule` pattern, isn't that going to try to match the URL from the very beginning?

Comment: This answer is actually correct - not sure what you mean by match the URL at the very beginning... Is it just not redirecting?

Comment: This works for something like `http://localhost/index.php/blah`, but not `http://localhost/site1/index.php/blah` (assuming that my `.htaccess` file is in the `/site1` directory relative to my document root).

Comment: If your .htaccess is in `site1` then you need a `RewriteBase` (see updated rule).

Comment: Isn't there a way to do a regex match of the base?  Otherwise, it will require every user of my software to configure their `.htaccess` individually.  I don't want to add that extra level of complexity.

Comment: ok check updated rules, it will generate rewrite base dynamically

Comment: Hmm, still no luck.  I'm running Apache 2.4.4, if that is any help.  Can we discuss in chat?

Comment: I've tested this run in Apache 2.4.4 and in subdirectory. `http://localhost/site/index.php/account/login` gets redirected to `http://localhost/site/account/login`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You'd think it would be that simple but alas...no :(